What payload can one stepper motor step reliably move / how long does one step take?
My group is making a telescope mount that rotates a payload very slowly, after many gear reductions, to match the motion of the night sky. After our gear reductions we need about a half second between each step (the rotation being discretized into individual steps is intentional). We originally planned to use the A4988 stepper driver chip to control a NEMA 17 stepper, but think we have to ditch this control method due to the problem here.
I'm failing to understand how to determine the payload this step would be able to move safely. Knowing the angle that the payload would rotate, the amount of torque necessary to perform the rotation is still dependent on the time taken; the time of the step itself, not the time between steps.
All the resources I've found online investigate the performance of steppers at high RPM's but I am specifically interested in the dynamics and performance of a single step, and how this relates to the moment of inertia which it can reliably rotate without skipping. As a mechanical engineer, I think we want a single step to take a "long" amount of time (say, a tenth of a second?) in order to avoid the huge torque necessary to accelerate and decelerate the payload too quickly, but I don't know where to start when it comes to controlling or simply determining this amount of time, not to mention how it would affect the actual torque output.
This isn't a single concise question, so anything that might help my group move in the right direction is invaluable. Thank you.

1 Don't forget the friction in the gear reduction. 2 If the centre of mass of the payload doesn't coincide with centre of rotation, then possible torque due to gravity also needs to be accounted for.

If you want to control the speed of a single step, consider using "microstepping". Your A4988 is already capable of doing this.
Other ways to control torque include using shaft couplings with damping.
I have to say, I'm very curious about the decision to use such a slow stepping rate, accelerating and decelerating the load with each step — assuming your gear train is stiff enough to do that without significant overshoot or backlash. Stepping every half second means that you've got a built-in pointing error of 7.5 arc seconds peak-to-peak (worst case, less if you slow down the steps). How does this fit into your overall error budget?

Let's ignore the friction for now
We assume your telescope is a well-balanced disk and concentric with the torque vector (otherwise it will wobble) with a moment of inertia of $I.$
We calculate the torque needed to start this disk from pause and accelerate it, then decelerate it to stand still within your time and rotation angle parameter. Then you add the friction and check to see what stepper driver can support this torque.

$\theta= step \ rotation$
$I= moment \ of \ inertia$
$\omega= average\ rotation\ speed$
$t=step\ time$

$$ \tau= 2\frac{I\omega^2}{2} = I\omega^2$$
The factor of 2 is because the disk is accelerating half the cycle and 2nd half decelerating.
$$\omega= \frac{\theta}{2t}$$
$$\tau=I*[\frac{\theta}{2t}]^2 $$
